# Is it possible to create an atom theme with transparent background?

Tags: atom-editor, opacity

So i want to have my atom transparent, for ease of use when coding without further screens on my laptop. I dislike the solutions for getting atom transparent ([,like in this post, as it seems quite messy](https://github.com/transcranial/atom-transparency)). Now i'm interested, whether it would be possible to make an atom theme, which makes atom transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to tap into the electron attributes.  More specifically, the new BrowserWindow function:

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow({transparent: true, frame: false})
win.show()
```

I have not made an atom theme before, but I have attempted to make an electron app.  As you can tell, making a [frameless transparent browser window](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md#transparent-window) is probably your goal.  From there on, you would want to adjust the opaque attribute of the transparency.  I think CSS is your friend there.  Even in the theme link that you posted suggests to modify the CSS file to customize the opacity to your likings.